# how to use only 1 return in this recursive method

Tags: java

I'm finishing up the easy portion project and my professor specified that he only wants methods with at maximum 1 return. I can't seem to figure out how to make this work correctly with only 1 return though. For context, I am finding how many nodes in a tree have exactly 1 non-null children.

```
// How many nodes have exactly 1 non-null children
    public int stickCt() { 
        return stickCt(root);
    }
    private int stickCt(StringNode t) { 
        int count = 0;
        if (t == null)
            return 0;
        
        else if ((t.getLeft() == null && t.getRight() != null) || (t.getLeft() != null & t.getRight() == null))
            count++;
        
        count = count + stickCt(t.getLeft()) + stickCt(t.getRight());
        return count;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private int stickCt(StringNode t) { 
    int count = 0;
    if (t != null) {
        if ((t.getLeft() == null && t.getRight() != null) || (t.getLeft() != null & t.getRight() == null))
            count++;
        count += stickCt(t.getLeft()) + stickCt(t.getRight());
    }
    return count;
}
```

However, in this case I find your formulation with the 2 returns easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using recursive algorithm you can use BFS of DFS algorithm.

Here is an example or BSF approach

```
public int stickCt(StringNode root){
        int count = 0;

        Queue<StringNode > queue = new LinkedList<StringNode >();
        queue.add(root);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()){ 
            StringNode tempNode = queue.poll();

            if (tempNode != null && (tempNode.getLeft() == null && tempNode.getRight() != null) || (tempNode.getLeft() != null && tempNode.getRight() == null)){
                count++;
            }
           
            /*Enqueue left child */
            if (tempNode.getLeft()!= null) { 
                queue.add(tempNode.getLeft()); 
            } 
  
            /*Enqueue right child */
            if (tempNode.getRight()!= null) { 
                queue.add(tempNode.getRight()); 
            }
        }
    
        return count; 
    }
```